# CSS overflow: hidden not working with button

Tags: html, css, button, flexbox, overflow

Why is `.div2` size taken into account inside `.div1` even though `.button` has `overflow: hidden` ?

**EDIT:** As you can see `.div1` has a `height` of 150px (corresponding to `.div2`) instead of 50px (corresponding to `.button`).

Only adding `display: flex` seems to be working. Why ?

```css
.div1 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.div2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.button {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* display: flex; */
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <button class="button">
    <div class="div2"></div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "adding display: flex seems to be working."? Be working in what way? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Your code works well in my device.

Comment: Makes no difference to me (Edge/Windows10) whether have the display flex in there or not.  There is no overflowing and it looks OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, look like your just practicing some CSS.
Try adding a fix width to the button and then the `overflow: hidden;` will take into effect. Also buttons have a display of inline-block by default so they automatically adjust to the size of there content or child.

```css
.div1 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.div2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.button {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* display: flex; */
}

.button-1 {
 width: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <button class="button">
  BEFORE
    <div class="div2"></div>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="div1">
  <button class=" button button-1">
  AFTER
    <div class="div2"></div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I see what is happening. Adding a ```width``` to the button doesn't resolve the issue. However, adding ```some text``` in the button does resolve the issue! Is it a bug or a wanted behaviour?

Comment: Adding `display: block` to `.button` also fixes the issue. As you said button elements have a `display: inline-block` which is why they act as it is. However I still don't understand why adding *some text* in `.button` fixes the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overflow: hidden; you want to set the visibility to hidden like this.

visibility: hidden;